# List of all available environment variables available in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, environment-variables

Apple lets you access system environment variables in SwiftUI like this.

```swift
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass
```

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues) about the @Environment property wrapper.

I can not seem to locate a list of all available environment variables. Does anyone know of such a list?

Comment: The page you linked to has all of the non-custom `EnvironmentValue`s. Do you mean also enumerating through custom ones?

Comment: Cmd-ctrl-click in Xcode on `.horizontalSizeClass` and. you'll get into place of SwiftUI module interface where all `EnvironmentValue`s are declared around.